# subscribe next parameter types error in angular

Tags: node.js, arrays, angular, node-modules

I shared my error and code below. Somehow I cannot understand why the error is caused. Can you help me?

My code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ProductService} from '../../services/product.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.scss']
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {

  products: any[] = [];

  constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.productService.getAllProducts().subscribe((prods: {count: Number, products: any[]}) => {
     this.products = prods.products;
     console.log(this.products);
   });

  }
}
```

My Error:
[my error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtxSU.png)

Comment: What does your `getAllProducts` method looks like? It seems to have a different return type

Comment: getAllProducts(numberOfResults = 10) {
    return this.http.get(this.SERVER_URL + '/products', {
      params: {
        limit: numberOfResults.toString()
      }
    });
  }

Comment: What happens if you cast it to `this.http.get<{count: Number, products: any[]}>(this.SERVER_URL..`

Comment: in getallproduct or in subscribe?

Comment: Inside your `getAllProducts` method, the `http.get` line

Comment: Thank you very much at the moment working. You don't know how happy I was :))

Comment: Nice, I'll provide it as an answer then :-)

Comment: i don't know how to confirm your answer

Comment: You can do it like this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/346766

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should typecast your `http.get` method

```js
getAllProducts(numberOfResults = 10) { 
  return this.http.get<{count: Number, products: any[]}>(this.SERVER_URL + '/products', { params: { limit: numberOfResults.toString() } }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  products: any[] = [];
  constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.productService.getAllProducts().subscribe((prods: IPerson) => {
     this.products = prods.products;
   });
  }
}
interface IPerson{
  count:number,
  products:any[]
}
```

service:

```
getAllProducts(){
  return this http.get(`url`);
}
```

But it is better to use the following method:

```
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  products: any[] = [];
  constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.productService.getAllProducts().subscribe(prods=> {
     this.products = prods.products;
   });
  }
}
export interface IPerson{
  count:number,
  products:any[]
}
```

service:

```
getAllProducts():Observble<IPerson>{
  return this http.get<IPerson>(`url`);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried it but unfortunately this code did not work for my application.